# ¿Cómo hacer referencia a un input type="text" con Razor en MVC?

Tags: c#, mvc, razor

Tengo un textBox de name="txt" pero cuando quiero hacer referencia a ese textBox no me lo reconoce aca mi código:

```
<input type="text" name="txt" placeholder="Buscar libro" />

@if(txt.Text == "")
{
//do something
}
```

Visual studio me dice que el nombre txt no existe en el contexto actual, entonces como hago para hacer referencia al control textBox adentro del if?

Comment: Creo que estas confundiendo tecnologias. Lo que intentas hacer es posible en webforms no en MVC. Que es lo que necesitas  hacer? A ver si puedo darte una ayuda.

Comment: Gracias! lo que quiero saber es simple, como hacer referencia a un textBox en el .cshtml. Mi idea es que si el usuario no escribe nada..le muestre una lista completa de libros, y si escribe por ejemplo el nombre de un libro, me traiga solo ese libro, (ya tengo las funciones hechas para traer el listado) pero por eso mismo quiero saber como hacer referencia a ese textBox de name="txt" para que dependiendo de lo que haya escrito o no el usuario haga lo que corresponda.

Comment: Eso lo raelizas con puro javascript :)

Comment: Pero no existe una manera de poder hacer referencia a un elemento html como un simple textBox en MVC, razor sin usar javascript ?

Comment: Razor y sus etiquetas con `@` solo funcionan cuando se *entrega* la página al navegador. Una vez que la página está en el cliente, cualquier programación que le quieras hacer va con Javascript.

Comment: Gracias @KroneauxSchneider! ambos tenemos el mismo apellido jaja!